# How do i vertically align a tikz picture inside a beamer frame

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, vertical-alignment

The beamer frames optinal argument `[c]` seems to be ignored in the following example:

```
\begin{frame}[c, fragile, shrink] %seems to be ignored, not aligning vertically 
    \makebox[\textwidth][c]{ % works, aligning horizontally
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[draw]{Center Me};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{frame}
```

How do i need to modify the example to center the node vertically?

Comment: Incidentally, a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/86) starts (at least) with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.  Sometimes problems are due to package clashes and it's hard to debug them without knowing what packages are being loaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the `shrink` option.  If you remove that then the frame is vertically centred.  My guess is that since `shrink` is meant for cramming stuff that is too big onto the page, the `c` option gets ignored since if `shrink` is needed, vertical alignment goes out of the window as the box will fill the entire page.